# Change persisted class in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence

I have my `User` class, which has its own table, and the `Organizer` class, which also has its own table and is a specialization of `User`. How do I make an already persisted `User` in JPA become an `Organizer` while keeping the same ID value

```
public class OrganizadorService {

    private final OrganizadorRepository organizerRepository;
    private final UsuarioRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public OrganizadorService(OrganizadorRepository organizerRepository, UsuarioRepository userRepository) {
        this.organizerRepository = organizerRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean transformToOrganizer(long id) {
        try {
            organizerRepository.transformToOrganizer(id);
            //entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
            entityManager.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.SunLovers.PriseTheSun.model.Organizer;

@Repository
public interface OrganizerRepository extends JpaRepository<Organizer, Long> {
  
    @Modifying
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "INSERT INTO organizer (ID) VALUES (:id)")
    @Transactional
    void transformToOrganizer(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd change the model. Since it seems an `User` may become an `Organizer` inheritance is not the right tool to solve this.
Instead let the `User` have an optional `OrganizerRole`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would want my transformToOrganizer in my Organizer Service to look like.

i)fetch the user entity by User Id from the user table.

UserEntity user = userRepository.findById(id);

ii)We have our user entity, now I assume the user-to-organizer relationship is @OneToOne and user id is the primary key in the organizer table. We create a new organizer entity and set the necessary details along with it we set organizer.setUser(user).

Please post your entity definitions here for more clarity.

Comment: my user uses "@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)" and my organizer extends my user. basically that's it

Comment: A simple work around maybe to add a flag column is_organizer to the User table so we can store all user details along with whether they are organizers or not.